# Android stop backward navigation

Tags: android, callback

I'm implementing a game for android platform. The game is nearly ready, but I got a weird problem:

When a player completes game, a "congratulations, you win" page is displayed. A button from that view is redirecting to main page.
The problem arises when player clicks back button, because game is displayed again.

Is there a way to control what back button behavior should appear? like redirect to main page always

Thank you in advance

Comment: finish your game activity before you navigate to the congrats! activity

Comment: on which platform you are developing game?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for.

```
Intent a = new Intent(DisplayPage.this,MainPage.class);
a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(a);
```

This will surely help you.

Comment: In fact, seems that is not working as intended. Back button continues to perform its action.

Comment: I found a better solution: @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
Just override onBackPressed without any implementation, and thats all :)

Comment: Great but you didn't mention that your "Winning Page" is a Dialog box or Activity itself otherwise i would have suggested you to use this backPress method. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Just override that function without implementation, and then, back button functionality will disappear as needed.